# Advanced SQL Update - User Defined Fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that uses and very large handful of User Defines Fields driven by a field named **udfindex**.  This can be one of hundreds of 1 to 3 digit numbers.  The key value tied to the index is **udjoin**.

My issue is this. I need to update the **udvalue** of anything tied to **udfindex** 18 to be the last two characters of **udvalue** tied to **udfindex** 31 for specific **udjoins**.

Example:

I currently have

```
udjoin     | udfindex | udvalue 
12345-001  |    31    | Superior Court, San Francisco, CA  
12345-001  |    18    |  NULL
```

How can I run a SQL query to update the **udvalue** tied to this **udjoin** to represent the following:

```
udjoin     | udfindex | udvalue 
12345-001  |    31    | Superior Court, San Francisco, CA  
12345-001  |    18    |  CA
```

Any assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards,

-Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do a join on same table, with some filters.

Something like that (of course do a select first to be sure you've got what you want before doing this as an update)

```
update t1
set t1.udvalue = substring(t2.udvalue, LEN(t2.udvalue)-1, 2)
from yourTable t1
join yourTable t2 on t1.udjoin = t2.udjoin and t2.udfindex = 31
where t1.udfindex = 18
--and t1.udjoin ='something'
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6ee6c/1)

Comment: Thank you Raphaël Althaus.  But how I can do this specific to the t2.udvalue being "CA".  I don't want to do this across the board, only for specific instances.

Comment: @NCollinsTE hmmm, not sure i understand, you wrote about "2 last chars" in your question, as that's what's happening here...

Comment: I was able to figure it out based off of your logic.  Thank you.

UPDATE t1
SET t1.udvalue = 'CA' 
FROM udf t1
JOIN udf t2 on t1.udjoin = t2.udjoin and t2.udfindex = '31'
where substring(t2.udvalue, LEN(t2.udvalue)-1, 2) = 'CA' AND 
 t1.udfindex = '18' and
 t1.udjoin LIKE '011580-%'